# Select box issue with "sign" effect of jquery-custombox in mozilla

Tags: css, mozilla

Options of select field are moving away from selected field inside the lightbox only on mozilla and working fine on Chrome.

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gpmex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below CSS

```
.custombox-show.custombox-sign .custombox-modal-content {
            transform: none;
            transform-style: initial;
        }
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvGzL)